# Ruby Timeout::timeout doesn't fire Exception and doesn't return what documented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timeout, rescue

I have this piece of code:

```
begin
  complete_results = Timeout.timeout(4) do      
    results = platform.search(artist, album_name)
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts 'Print me something please'
end
```

I then launch the method containing this code, and well, here is the beginning of a stack trace:

```
Exception message :  execution expired
Exception backtrace :  /***/****/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:64:i
```

So I naively thinks that my call timed out, but 'Print me something please' is never printed and `complete_results` which is suppose to be the timeout status return value (either true or false, as mentioned in the documentation), is definitively not a boolean.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your code is correct

```
require 'timeout'
begin
  complete_results = Timeout.timeout(1) do      
   sleep(2)
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts 'Print me something please'
end
```

does print out "print me something please".

Try the basic code as above. If that works, you have an issue in `platform.search`.

Comment: You were definitively right. I Don't know why i didn't check platform.search. Actually, search was rescueing.. Exception... Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `platform.search` is catching the exception that `Timeout#timeout throws`.

You can get around this by wrapping your inner code in another thread -- YMMV.

```
begin
  complete_results = Timeout.timeout(4) do
    Thread.new{ results = platform.search(artist, album_name) }.value
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  puts 'Print me something please'
end
```

Comment: I recently described and, possibly, fixed this problem, here: http://code.jjb.cc/2012/09/15/sane_timeout-a-replacement-for-rubys-standard-library-timeout/

Comment: Timeout does suck, but this Threaded approach works well, thanks

Comment: or try soft_timeout [https://github.com/abhi-patel/soft_timeout](https://github.com/abhi-patel/soft_timeout)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://railsapi.com/doc/ruby-v1.8/classes/Timeout.html#M003543):

> If the block execution terminates
>   before sec seconds has passed, it
>   returns true. If not, it terminates
>   the execution and raises exception
>   (which defaults to Timeout::Error)

This means it only returns true if it's successful, otherwise the variable will not be set (ie it's nil NOT false).

As far as your example goes, it's definitely timing out for me and getting to the rescue part...