# Inconsistent Timeout::timeout and rescue Timeout::Error behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, rescue

I'm using `Timeout::timeout(1)` for a process that takes longer than 1 second, though it only occasionally triggers a timeout. When it does, `rescue` captures it in different ways each time. Here's a sample of my code:

```
require 'timeout'
...
begin
  status = Timeout::timeout(1) {
    open(file_url) do |foo|
      feed = RSS::Parser.parse(foo)
      some_method_call(arg1, arg2)
      #other stuff
    end
  }
rescue Timeout::Error
  Rails.logger.debug "Timeout"
  return nil
rescue Exception => ex
  Rails.logger.debug "EXCEPTION - #{ex.message}"
  return nil
end
```

Here are the three scenarios I encounter with the same input:

- Process runs to completion and takes longer than 60 seconds
- Process times out and hangs, printing only `execution expired` in `development.log`
- Process times out, is rescued properly, prints `"Timeout"` in `development.log`, and returns `nil`

Why is this so inconsistent?

**UPDATE**

After reducing the timeout to 0.0001s, the process is timing out consistently and as expected. It seems that the `open(file_url)` block was opening faster than 1 second, and despite everything within the block taking more than 1 second, the `Timeout` was only triggered if the opening itself took longer than 1 second.

This however did not explain the `execution expired` exception. To test this, I moved the `Timeout::timeout(0.0001)` to within the `open` block. The code looks like the following:

```
require 'timeout'
...
begin
  open(file_url) do |foo|
    status = Timeout::timeout(0.0001) do
      begin
        feed = RSS::Parser.parse(foo)
        some_method_call(arg1, arg2)
        #other stuff
      rescue Timeout::Error
        Rails.logger.debug "Timeout 2"
      rescue Exception => ex
        Rails.logger.debug "EXCEPTION 2 - #{ex.message}"
      end
    end
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  Rails.logger.debug "Timeout"
  return nil
rescue Exception => ex
  Rails.logger.debug "EXCEPTION - #{ex.message}"
  return nil
end
```

Now, I'm consistently receiving the output `EXCEPTION 2 - execution expired`. Why is it that the `Timeout::Error` is not being triggered here?

Comment: This looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637282/ruby-timeouttimeout-doesnt-fire-exception-and-doesnt-return-what-documented?rq=1

Comment: Are you catching any exceptions inside the `timeout` block?

Comment: @Stefan - I tried testing for exceptions inside, and I am indeed receiving exceptions within. Check the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner

```
rescue Exception => ex
  Rails.logger.debug "EXCEPTION 2 - #{ex.message}"
end
```

keeps the outer `timeout`block from raising `Timeout::Error`.

Removing that `rescue`statement should do the trick.

If you really need to catch any exception, replace it with:

```
rescue StandardError => ex
  Rails.logger.debug "EXCEPTION 2 - #{ex.message}"
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't the inner `timeout` block have raised an exception?

Answer (score 1):

Internally (within the Timeout block) Timeout does not use Timeout::Error. If it did, then every garden-variety rescue would catch it, and you don't want that. So it creates a new Exception and uses that, so that it hopefully blows through all normal error handling and actually makes the code stop running.

Check out the timeout.rb code in ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0. It's quite short, and pretty informative.

In particular, you can pass your own Exception in as the second parameter of Timeout::timeout, and Timeout will use that. So you can catch it inside your code, if you want.

Note that Logger currently traps all exceptions that happen while writing, and doesn't re-raise, so it breaks Timeout. I've filed a bug report.